# paypal recurring payment ipn

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a paypal recurring payment for monthly payment. But, still recurring payment not reflecting in my paypal account. please check below IPN is proper way to create recurring payment or not.

```
[TOKEN] => EC-4UK058186M302872U
[BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 0
[CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
[TIMESTAMP] => 2016-10-13T07:23:01Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 802503fea2809
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 94
[BUILD] => 26106709
[EMAIL] => paulmaxxxxxx@gmail.com
[PAYERID] => 74738MRYPKYKJ
[PAYERSTATUS] => verified
[FIRSTNAME] => Sekar
[LASTNAME] => New
[COUNTRYCODE] => IN
[SHIPTONAME] => Sekar New
[SHIPTOSTREET] => Flat no. 507 Wing A Raheja Residency
[SHIPTOSTREET2] => Film City Road, Goregaon East
[SHIPTOCITY] => Mumbai
[SHIPTOSTATE] => Maharashtra
[SHIPTOZIP] => 400097
[SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => IN
[SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => India
[ADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[AMT] => 1.00
[SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
[HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
[TAXAMT] => 0.00
[DESC] => Songplay Booking
[INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
[SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 1.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => Songplay Booking
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Sekar New
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => Flat no. 507 Wing A Raheja Residency
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2] => Film City Road, Goregaon East
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Mumbai
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => Maharashtra
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 400097
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => IN
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => India
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
[PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thank you! may i know which part i have mistaken.

Comment: Hmm ... good point ... For me it's just not obvious what you trying to achieve and it does not look like a [mcve]. Hopefully I'm wrong and you get the answer you want.